# Cut text block in two parts, based on finding a tag wihin the text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This should be simple, once I figure out how, so I'm interested in the various ways to solve this while I search for an answer.

I have a what is essentially a db text field of html. I need to cut this in two parts based on finding a tag within the text.

In simple(but imagine this is a gigantic block of html):

```
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum {CUT} lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

I need to be able to deconstruct this into two parts, based on a {CUT} tag in the text. I've not done this yet, but imagine its been done.

What is the most efficient way to do this with Ruby? It is in a rails app, so if there is something rails(ish) to simplify this I'm unaware know of, that would be great. There is probably a thread here on stackoverflow, but I haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block of HTML is so gigantic that a `string.split("{CUT}")` won't cut it?

`split("{CUT}", 2)` will split it in, *at most*, two pieces, based on the first occurence of {CUT}.

Comment: Like I said, simple and basic, I hadn't done anything like this and I was looking for the simplest, most direct way without overengineering an html parser library and a whole afternoon. Thanks.